# Are derived classes considered friends?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

If I create base class A and A is a friend of class B, can a class derived from A access B to its liking, or else what is it allowed?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
struct A{};

struct Ader : A{};

struct B{
   friend struct A;
};
```

No. Friendship is not inherited in C++. It is also not transitive.

`Ader` can not access `B` as a friend unless explicitly given friendship by B, just because it's base `A` is a friend of `B`.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not allowed. Check [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html).