# How to use friend class but introduce less dependence

Tags: c++

Project A, **PA.h**:

```
#include "Common.h"

class PA
{
   void func()
   {
     Common::getInstance()->cm();
     Common::getInstance()->onlyCallByPA();
   }
}
```

Project Common, **Common.h**:

```
class Common
{
    SINGLETON
public:
  void cm(){}
 private:
    //I do not want PB to call onlyCallByPA
    //so I want to add class PA to friend class
    //so I need to include PA.h
    //but if I include PA.h, PB.cpp  include PA.h 
    //this will make PA.h expose to PB
    //I do not want PB to include PA.h
  void onlyCallByPA(){}
}
```

Project B, **PB.cpp**:

```
#include "Common.h"

class PB
{
    //I need to call cm() but PB do not be allowed to call onlyCallByPA
    //and also do not be allowed to include PA.h
}
```

So I want to make `PA` as `Common`'s friend class but this will introduce dependence to `PB`.
Any better solution? Or, can I use other design to implement what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Use a forward declaration. This will allow you to declare the friendship without including the header or relying on the full class declaration of `PA`.

Common.h

```
class PA; // forward declaration.

class Common
{
    friend PA;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
friend return_type class_name::function(args);

class Common 
{

    // ...

    friend void PA::OnlyCallByPA(); // Only PA has access
};
```

//EDIT

Make a base class for PA and introduce only the base class in "Common.h"

Comment: Still need to include PA.h

Comment: The second suggestion will likely not work as you are expecting because [friendship is not inherited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4083875/845568).